# Is is safe to use function reference as an object property/key

Tags: javascript, performance, cross-browser

Are there any reasons why I should not do use a function reference as the property/key of a object ? This code works in Chrome, Firefox, & IE8, but "just because something works..."

```
var x = {}

var a = function() { return 'a' };
var b = function() { return 'b' };

x[a] = 1
x[b] = 2

x[a] === x[a] // returns true
x[a] === x[b] // returns false
x[b] === x[b] // returns true
x[a] // returns 1
x[b] // returns 2
```

Comment: Two different functions with the same body would serialize to the same string. This might not be desired.

Comment: Oh FYI, ECMAScript 6 will introduce proper maps: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:simple_maps_and_sets. Any value/object can be a key then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object Keys are string. What is used in `x[a]` is in fact `x[a.toString()]`.

This means that your function as key is exactly the same key as a string :

```
x[a] === x["function () { return 'a' }"]
```

So yes, you might consider it both unsafe and unreasonable. It's hard to imagine a context in which it would be useful or efficient.

Comment: See that's what I thought, about key's being strings, but Chrome's debugger was throwing me off since it doesn't show quotes about the keys. `var x = {'1': 'a'}; x;` prints out `Object {1: "a"}`.